# deep copying userControl

Tags: c#

According to this article [deep copying](http://csharp.2000things.com/2010/11/07/143-an-example-of-implementing-icloneable-for-deep-copies/), I'm trying to make a deep copy of my userControl. 
So in my main viewModel I have:

```
public object Clone()
    {
        var cloneControl = (ISelectableViewModel) SelectedObject; //SelectedObject it's current userControl
        return cloneControl.Clone();

    }
```

My usercontrol have also simple usercontrol inside. So code for userControl Clone method is:

```
 public override object Clone()
    {
        var partikel1Clone = (UserControl05Partikel1ViewModel) MemberwiseClone();
        partikel1Clone.UserControl1.ViewModel = (ISelectableViewModel) UserControl1.ViewModel.Clone();
        return partikel1Clone;
    }
```

And my simple userControl's Clone method is:

```
 public override object Clone()
 {
     return MemberwiseClone();
 }
```

The problem is that my cloned object changes, when I change main object. Any ideas where am I wrong?

Comment: Memberwise Clone is only one level deep.

Comment: @Henk yes, but I am calling Clone method for my inside control which calls another Memberwise

Comment: I would consider Controls (UIElements) as not clonable... You don't own the source and there's 15 layers of inheritance in play here.

Comment: You would be better to come up with a separate description of the "copyable" bits of the control, e.g add a method to list them out into xml, json, even name value, and then add a  constructor that took the description as an argument. What you are doing is complex and way too fragile as you don't own most of the code.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson thnx for advice. I'll give a try

Comment: why you need a clone? what you wanna achive?

Comment: @blindmeis I have a propertyGrid, where user can edit properties of userControl. For udno operation I'm creating deepCopy of userControl properties

Comment: Isn't that going to eat memory like a mother?

Comment: What's UserControl1? I do not see this one cloned specifically, and I assume that it is an object? If it is, memberwise cloning just copies the reference to that object, and not the object itself.

Answer (score -2):

Binary serialisation is probably the simplest way to do a true deep clone.

```
using(var stream = new MemoryStream())
{

    var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    formatter.serialize(stream, objectToClone);
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    return (MyType)formatter.Deserialize(stream);    
}
```

Comment: It does not help me, because during serialization I get errors like Type 'System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush' in Assembly 'PresentationCore, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' is not marked as serializable.